# always last database line is deleted when deleting from php page

Tags: php, mysqli, delete-row

Im fetching data from database table when i m trying to delete a particular record no matter what i click last record get deleted what m i doing wrong, this is code m using after submit/click del button

```
// DELETE

if(isset($_POST['del']))
{
require'conn.php';
$delete_id = $_POST['del_id'];
print_r($_POST);
die;

$del_stmt = "DELETE FROM signup WHERE ID =$delete_id";
mysqli_query($conn,$del_stmt);
mysqli_execute($del_stmt);
$row=mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
if($row==1)
{
echo "<h1>".' sucess ! record was deleted' ."</h1>";
}
else
{
echo "<h1>".' record was not deleted '."</h1>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}
include'fetchtable.php';
```

and this is my table structure and del button code

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

<?php
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'";
echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Gender</td><td>Email</td><td>Password</td><td>Delete</td><td>Edit</td>";
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$fn" ."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$ln" ."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$gen"."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$email"."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$pass" ."</td>";
echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="del_id" value="'.$id.'" />'. '<input type="submit" name="del" value="delete" /> ';
echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="'.$id.'" />'.' <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit" /> ';
echo"</tr>";
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: where do you assign a value to $id ?

Comment: Because you have one form and inside that multiple submit so onsubmit the $_POST['del_id'] will always be the last element in the DOM..

Comment: please echo $id and see what value you get.

Comment: @IanKenney <?php
require 'conn.php';
$tfetch = "select ID,firstname,lastname,gender,email, password from signup";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare ($conn,$tfetch))
{
 mysqli_stmt_execute ($stmt); 
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result ($stmt, $id, $fn, $ln, $gen, $email, $pass );
 mysqli_stmt_store_result ($stmt);
 
}
mysqli_close ($conn);

?>

Comment: @Abhishekkadadi so what should i do !! can you suggest some changes cos if im assigning the $id value to the submit button (then it shows id instead of delete ) its workin but when m assiging to a hidden felid it is not

Comment: As @AbhikChakraborty says you have one form with multiple rows, move the form definition within the while loop so there is one for for each row

Comment: @wittyvishwas on submit button button only you will get data on post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Abhik Chakraborty says, you need a form for each row, or an other logic;

one solution is to put the `<form ...>...</form>` within the loop:

*this is - AFAIK - not correct, in does not conform to HTML std. and works only with some browsers, bcause `<table>` and `<form>` ar mixed in wrong order, I use it only as egsample to show you problem*

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'";
echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Gender</td><td>Email</td><td>Password</td><td>Delete</td><td>Edit</td>";
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
echo "<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">"
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$fn" ."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$ln" ."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$gen"."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$email"."</td>";
echo "<td>". "$pass" ."</td>";
echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="del_id" value="'.$id.'" />'. '<input type="submit" name="del" value="delete" /> ';
echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="'.$id.'" />'.' <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit" /> ';
echo"</tr>";
echo "</form>"
```

I would preferre to have only one hidden field in the form und to set the value of that field with `onClick` event of the submit button.

only the last lines again:

```
...
echo '<td> <input type="submit" name="del" value="delete" onclick="form.row_id.value='$the id$';"/>'
echo '<td> <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit" onclick="form.row_id.value='$the id$';"/>'
echo"</tr>";
}
?>
<input ID='row_id' type="hidden" name="del_id" value="no set till now" />'
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have multiple for each action and so you need to have the code as

```
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">' ;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
    echo "<td>". "$fn" ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". "$ln" ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". "$gen"."</td>";
    echo "<td>". "$email"."</td>";
    echo "<td>". "$pass" ."</td>";
    echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="del_id" value="'.$id.'" />'. '<input type="submit" name="del" value="delete" /> ';
    echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="'.$id.'" />'.' <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit" /> ';
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";

}
```

Also your code is not safe, you need to use mysqli_real_escape_string() for your POST data. or prepared statement

Comment: @abhicharborty THANX you are life saver!! was googlin it for whole day .. thanx mate